# Highcharts series update with animation

Tags: javascript, animation, charts, highcharts

I can update the data value of a spider chart and see it animated using this method:

```
chart.series[i].setData(newSeries[i].data);
```

But, as the series in a spider chart consists not only of `data` but also other fields, as in

```
series: [{
            name: 'Allocated Budget',
            data: [43000, 19000, 60000, 35000, 17000, 10000],
            pointPlacement: 'on'
        }, {
            name: 'Actual Spending',
            data: [50000, 39000, 42000, 31000, 26000, 14000],
            pointPlacement: 'on'
        }]
```

**Along with the data, when I need to change the value `name: 'Actual Spending'` , how can I update the series with animation?**

Because, for example if I call:

```
chart.series[i].update({series: newSeries[i] , name : newName});
```

There won't be any animation.

If it is still unclear... Well, sometimes a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/skeletorkun/my8646oc/4/) is worth a 100 words.

Comment: Hey @Josh . set data redraws by default. http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#Series.setData

Comment: i can set the data, no problem with that. But how do i change the other fields? 'setName' per se ?

Comment: I'm not sure what kind of animation do you expect when updating series name? See demo: http://jsfiddle.net/j522sdbk/

Comment: @PawełFus as in : http://jsfiddle.net/skeletorkun/my8646oc/

Comment: @PawełFus ah now I understood what you mean..  no animation expectations from the 'name' value change of course. I just want to be able to update both data and name with an animation on the data change

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Update the `name`, then set the `data` with the desired animation:

```
chart.series[0].update({name:'new title'});
chart.series[0].setData(newData);
```

[See working fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/my8646oc/5/)

Answer (score 7):

Since the correct answer did not work for me with multiple series, I had to do it more similar to this:

First update the names since it's a quicker operation without animation.

```
// Pass false to skip redraw (since there are multiple operations, for better performance)
chart.series[0].update({name:'new title 0'}, false);
chart.series[1].update({name:'new title 1'}, false);
chart.series[2].update({name:'new title 2'}, false);
chart.series[3].update({name:'new title 3'}, false);

// Redraw the name changes before updating the data.
chart.redraw();

// Update the series data with animation, passing false to redraw here as well.
chart.series[0].setData(newData, false);
chart.series[1].setData(newData1, false);
chart.series[2].setData(newData2, false);
chart.series[3].setData(newData3, false);

// Now we redraw the series data
chart.redraw();
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a better solution

```
chart.update({ series: newSeries }, true, true, true);
```

**The third argument is the key:**

> update(options [, redraw] [, oneToOne] [, animation])

Comment: I have seen this answer in multiple places now, however the highcharts documentation doesn't show these arguments. Am I missing something? https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Series#update

Comment: You are checking the update class for Series. This is for the entire chart: https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Chart#update

Comment: Ah thanks Tiago, I was getting a lot of bugs trying to update multiple things so in the end I do all my updates like `series.setData(data, false);`, `chart.xAxis[0].update({ //stuff }, false);` and finally `chart.redraw({ duration: //milliseconds });`