# Highcharts: Placement of data labels in the middle of sections of Pie Chart

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts, pie-chart

I want the data labels of the pie chart to be displayed in the middle of the sections irrespective of:

1. Whether the section has been sliced or not
2. Whether the size attribute in plotOptions has been mentioned or not

**Solution 1**

For this, I tried using distance attribute of plotOptions. I got the radius from series[0].points[0].shapeArgs.r in load() event of chart. And then use following:

```
series[0].update({
    dataLabels: {
        distance: -(radius/2)
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/k94x958d/2/

But this poses two problem: Pie Chart Loading Animation is lost and if any section is sliced, data Labels are not placed correctly

http://jsfiddle.net/k94x958d/3/

**Solution 2**

To resolve animation issue, I tried using above logic to get distance and then setting it in series[0].options.dataLabels in overridden drawDataLabels() method of Highcharts Library. But it did not work.

Is there any way I can achieve placement of data labels in middle of pie sections irrespective of size, slicing etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use the following code in load event:

```
 series[0].update({
    animation: true,
    dataLabels: {
        distance: -(series[0].points[0].shapeArgs.r/2)
     }
 });

 _.each( series[0].points, function( point ) {
    var x = point.slicedTranslation.translateX + point.dataLabel.translateX,
        y = point.slicedTranslation.translateY + point.dataLabel.translateY;

    point.dataLabel.attr( {
        transform: 'translate(' + x + ',' + y + ')'
    } );
 });
```

The above code solves the problem of slicing and sizing. It seems that calling attr() preserves animation. The only problem which still remains is that animation is lost due to calling update().

**[Edit]**
The way data labels have been translated because of slicing, is there any way to translate them to middle of sections using attr()?

**[Edit]**
Solved.. Just put animation: true in update().

Answer (score 0):

This is an excellent question, and I particularly like your method for calculating the data label distance using the chart's radius (instead of using a fixed value).

I've been working with your fiddle for some time. Unfortunately, **I don't think what you're asking is possible**.

Since you want to move the data label for the sliced part of the pie so that it's in the center of that slice, it would make sense that you'd want to add the `slicedOffset` value to that data label's `distance` attribute.

I had imagined something like this:

```
events: {
  load: function() {
    var series = this.series[0],
        distance = series.points[0].shapeArgs.r / 2,
        pieOffset = this.options.plotOptions.pie.slicedOffset;
    $.each(series.points, function(index, value) {
      if (typeof value.sliced === "undefined") {
        value.update({
          dataLabels: { distance: -distance }
        });
      } else {
        value.update({
          dataLabels: { distance: -distance - pieOffset }
        });
      }
    });
  }
}
```

However, nothing changes. It appears that you can define the distances for data labels at a series level (or for the entire pie), but **not at the point level**.

According to the Highcharts API, you **should** be able to set any attribute for `series.data.dataLabels` as you would `plotOptions.series.dataLabels` (see http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#series<pie>.data.dataLabels), but only certain ones work (for example, if you set `rotation` for a specific point's data label, that shows up, but not `distance`).

Here's a modified version of your fiddle with my unsuccessful experiments: http://jsfiddle.net/brightmatrix/k94x958d/5/

Now, **to address your other item** about the series not animating when you update it, I think this may be because you're updating the series in your load event, and not afterwards by a separate event. There are several examples that show how you can use `setData()` or `setVisible()` to force an animation, but neither of those solutions worked when I updated the `load` event in your fiddle.

Here are the questions I researched:

- [Highcharts loading animation after setdata](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15987283/highcharts-loading-animation-after-setdata)
- [Highcharts series update with animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29549969/highcharts-series-update-with-animation)

In this case, perhaps you could have a jQuery event (outside of your chart options) that triggers on page load to force the animation.

I hope this information is helpful. I'm also hoping one of the Highcharts developers can weigh in on my research.